# how to remove trailing digit from code??

Tags: c#, winforms

my input is this 12 13 13 AF 3F 5f.
I need output the same.

I pass the input through client to server:

```
byte[] = system.text.encoding.ascii.getbyte(input);
```

and receive  at server side 
 `string some = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(output)`;

but I get excess  0's in the end of the byte almost around 1000's,

how do I trim this 0's with out changing  my byte array size

Comment: what is the length of output on server side?
byte[] = ... maybe it should be some array name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various options here:

`some = some.Substring(0, some.IndexOf('\0') + 1);` Or

`some = some.Remove(some.IndexOf('\0'));` Or

`some = some.TrimEnd('\0');`

Comment: Instead of creating a too long string and then trimming it, you can also use another overload of `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString` which specifies what segment of the byte array to decode.

Answer (score 2):

`ASCII` is 7-bit. Your value AF exceeds 7 bit, try to use `UTF8` encoding